# form validation is applying to login form but not for other forms

Tags: magento2, forms, validation

For me login form is working (used  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' in form and minlength:6 ).
But the same is not applying for the other forms

```
<form class="form-address-edit"
  action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSaveUrl()) ?>"
  method="post"
  id="form-validate"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
    <?= $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?>

    <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getAddress()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getAddress()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
        <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getAddress()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif ?>

</fieldset>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
    <div class="field street required">
        <label for="street_1" class="label">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address')) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text"
                   name="street[]"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine(1)) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address')) ?>"
                   id="street_1"
                   class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>"/>
            <div class="nested">
                <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                <?php for ($_i = 1, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i < $_n; $_i++): ?>
                    <div class="field additional">
                        <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i + 1 ?>">
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address %1', $_i + 1)) ?></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <input type="text" name="street[]"
                                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine($_i + 1)) ?>"
                                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i + 1)) ?>"
                                   id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i + 1 ?>"
                                   class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->isVatAttributeVisible()) : ?>
        <div class="field taxvat">
            <label class="label" for="vat_id">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('VAT Number')) ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="vat_id"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('VAT Number')) ?>"
                       class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('vat_id')) ?>"
                       id="vat_id">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field city required">
        <label class="label" for="city"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text"
                   name="city"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>"
                   class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>"
                   id="city">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field region required">
        <label class="label" for="region_id">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('State/Province')) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <select id="region_id" name="region_id"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>"
                    class="validate-select" <?= /* @noEscape */ !$block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>>
                <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
            </select>
            <input type="text"
                   id="region"
                   name="region"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRegion()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>"
                   class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region')) ?>"<?= !$block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field zip required">
        <label class="label" for="zip">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text"
                   name="postcode"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>"
                   id="zip"
                   class="input-text validate-zip-international <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode')) ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field country required">
        <label class="label" for="country"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Country')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->isDefaultBilling()): ?>
        <div class="message info">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("It's a default billing address.")) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultBilling()): ?>
        <div class="field choice set billing">
            <input type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" class="checkbox">
            <label class="label" for="primary_billing">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default billing address')) ?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($block->isDefaultShipping()): ?>
        <div class="message info">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("It's a default shipping address.")) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultShipping()): ?>
        <div class="field choice set shipping">
            <input type="checkbox" id="primary_shipping" name="default_shipping" value="1" class="checkbox">
            <label class="label" for="primary_shipping">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default shipping address')) ?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
    <?php endif; ?>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit"
                class="action save primary"
                data-action="save-address"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save Address')) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Save Address')) ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the telephone block

```
<div class="field telephone <?= $block->isRequired() ? 'required' : '' ?>">
<label for="telephone" class="label">
    <span>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?>
    </span>
</label>
<div class="control">
    <?php
        $_validationClass = $block->escapeHtmlAttr(
            $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')
                 ->getAttributeValidationClass('fax')
        );
    ?>
   <input type="text"
           name="telephone"
           id="telephone"
           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getTelephone()) ?>"
           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Numbers')) ?>"
           class="input-text <?= $_validationClass ?: '' ?>  "
           data-validate="{'required':true,'validate-length':true,'validate-number':true,'minlength':6,'maxlength':50}"

    />



</div>
```

telephone validation is not applying.

Comment: what you have tried? can you post your code?

Comment: <input type="text"
               name="telephone"
               id="telephone"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getTelephone()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Numbers')) ?>"
               class="input-text <?= $_validationClass ?: '' ?>  "
               data-validate="{'required':true,'validate-length':true,'validate-number':true,'minlength':6,'maxlength':50}"
               
        />

Comment: data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'  also used this in form

Comment: update your question with full form code

Comment: do you have any error on console?

Comment: I am getting no errors